# How can I get the total number of answers on any site?

Tags: support, answer-count

I am doing research which requires the total number of answers on Stack Overflow. Is there an approach for me to get it?

Comment: Note that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/10m) page (from when SO reached 10 million questions) still has a live counter, which is probably a few minutes more in time than serarch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type `is:answer` in the Stack Overflow search box. [That search reveals over 18 million answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer), not including those that have been deleted.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic has that info for all sites in one go.

Comment: @Mat true but it's heavily cached, so on sites like SO the difference can reach hundreds of answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can also leverage [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/451190) answers your question:

```sql
select sum(case when deletiondate is  null then 1 else 0 end) as answers
     , sum(case when deletiondate is not null then 1 else 0 end) as [deleted-answers]
     , count(*) as [total]
 from postswithdeleted
 where posttypeid =2 -- answers
```

Do know that SEDE is refreshed once a week, on monday.

At the day of posting the results are:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|  answers   |   deleted  |   total    |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 18,283,025 |  3,225,776 | 21,508,801 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```